# escape double quotes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How can I replace `double-quotes` to `&quote;` in a string?
This is what I have tried:

```
1.9.3-p362 :009 > a =  "\"That's it\", she said." 
 => "\"That's it\", she said." 
1.9.3-p362 :010 > a.tr('"', "&quote;")
 => "&That's it&, she said."
```

As you see instead of `&quotes;` I only get `&`, any idea?

Comment: this also worked for me: `a.gsub('"', '&quote;')`

Comment: That is because the strings passed to String#tr are actually sets of characters, like in the original Unix command `tr`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `gsub` instead

```
a.gsub(/\"/, "&quote;")

# without regex as noted by hirolau
a.gsub("\"", "&quote;")

# => "&quote;That's it&quote;, she said."
```

Comment: No reason to use regexp in this case. `a.gsub('"', '&quote;')`